# How to find limit of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve limits like this one?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^2} \right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{3^2} \right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \right) $$

Comment: Compute the first few terms to see if you spot a pattern. If you do, try to prove it (by induction or otherwise). For this one, experienced viewers see that it's a telescoping product. $$1 - \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{k^2-1}{k^2} = \frac{k-1}{k}\cdot\frac{k+1}{k}$$

Comment: Hint: take the logarithm and get two telescoping series.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then , I am not "experienced". Do you mean that the factors cancel out and only $\frac{1}{2}$ remains ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, the factors cancel out. After the factor $1 - \frac{1}{n^2}$, what remains is the $\frac{1}{2}$ from the first factor, and the $\frac{n+1}{n}$ from the last.

Comment: I know such tricks from infinite sums , but not from infinite products. Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=
\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}=
\frac{\prod_{k=2}^n(k-1)\prod_{k=2}^n(k+1)}{\prod_{k=2}^nk\prod_{k=2}^nk}
=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}k\prod_{k=3}^{n+1}k}{\prod_{k=2}^nk\prod_{k=2}^nk}.$$
Can you take it from here?